# How to have the count of rows from one table appear in the final table after a join?

Tags: sql, sas

I have two tables

T.1 looks like this:   (4 rows)

```
DTE_KEY_NUM Order   Date
9782        12345   10/12/22    
9782        12345   10/12/22    
9782        12345   10/12/22    
9782        12345   10/12/22
```

T.2 looks like this:   (1 row)

```
Order Num   Date       State

12345       10/12/22    MI
```

The outcome table shows one record:

```
Order Num   Date

12345       10/12/22
```

The tables are joined on the 'Order Num' column. I would like the final report to have only the one row, however have the count of rows from the first table. For example:

```
Order Num    Date       Line_Count

12345        10/12/22   4
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: What is the code you used to join the tables?  What did you try to get the count?

Comment: Just an inner join:  inner join t1 on t2.order_num = t1.order_num ;  to get the count I tried, count(t1.column_name) as total_lines

Comment: In the future please add any code attempted to your question directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's missing a  GROUP BY statement.

```
data t1;
input DTE_KEY_NUM $ Order  $  Date : ddmmyy10.;
format date ddmmyy10.;
cards;
9782        12345   10/12/22    
9782        12345   10/12/22    
9782        12345   10/12/22    
9782        12345   10/12/22    
;;;;


data t2;
input
Order_Num $  Date : ddmmyy10.      State $;
format date ddmmyy10.;
cards;
12345       10/12/22    MI
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
select t2.order_num, t2.date, count(t1.dte_key_num) as line_count
from t1
left join t2
on t1.order=t2.order_num and t1.date=t2.date
group by 1, 2;
quit;
```

Or an inline query though I usually find them inefficient.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select t2.order_num, t2.date, (select count(*) from t1 where t1.order=t2.order_num and t1.date=t2.date) as line_count
from t2;
quit;
```